# Understanding an exception message

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `All_companies` and I am comparing the `COMPANY_NUMBER` in column 1 with the next element in the same column

```
COMPANY_NUMBER      COMPANY_NAME
444444               ABC
444444               ABC
555555               XYZ
555555               XYZ
```

The code

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(All_companies)-1)) {
  if(All_companies[i, 1] == All_companies[i + 1, 1])
  {
    print("Match")
  } 
  else if (All_companies[i, 1] != All_companies[i + 1, 1])
  {
    print("No Match") 
  }
}
```

The code runs fine but I get an error after the code finishes running-

> Error in if (All_companies[i, 1] == All_companies[i + 1, 1]) { :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Any thoughts on how I can deal with this?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `NA`'s in the data?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand this syntax but shouldn't the main loop be `for (i in 1:(nrow(All_companies)-2)) {`?

Comment: with  (i in 1:(nrow(All_companies)-2))     it still gives exactly the same error

Answer (score 0):

If the comparison inside `if` statement is NA, then it exits with error:

```
if (NA) {
    print("Match")
}
#> Error in if (NA) print("Match") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

So, you probably have some `NA`'s in your `All_companies` dataset, because comparison of anything with `NA` is `NA`.

With `NA` it throws an error:

```
All_companies <- read.table(header = T, text = "
COMPANY_NUMBER      COMPANY_NAME
444444               ABC
444444               ABC
555555               XYZ
555555               XYZ
NA                   ABC
")

for (i in 1:(nrow(All_companies)-1)) {
  if (All_companies[i, 1] == All_companies[i + 1, 1])
  {
    print("Match")
  }
  else if (All_companies[i, 1] != All_companies[i + 1, 1])
  {
    print("No Match") 
  }
}
#> [1] "Match"
#> [1] "No Match"
#> [1] "Match"
#> Error in if (All_companies[i, 1] == All_companies[i + 1, 1]) {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Without NA it runs:

```r
All_companies <- read.table(header = T, text = "
COMPANY_NUMBER      COMPANY_NAME
444444               ABC
444444               ABC
555555               XYZ
555555               XYZ
")

for (i in 1:(nrow(All_companies)-1)) {
  if (All_companies[i, 1] == All_companies[i + 1, 1])
  {
    print("Match")
  }
  else if (All_companies[i, 1] != All_companies[i + 1, 1])
  {
    print("No Match") 
  }
}
#> [1] "Match"
#> [1] "No Match"
#> [1] "Match"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: There are no missing values however not all COMPANY_NUMBERS are numbers numeric some of them are alpha numeric    like 333333A

Comment: Hi @Ahson, the alpha numeric values should not matter... there must be another needle in a haystack. Please, check the output of `summary(All_companies)`, if there is any NA, NaN, NULL or something unexpected. The point is that your code seems to be OK, there's just some problem with the data column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there were missing values indeed. However, even with the missing value when I added `isTRUE` to the code it ran without error message.

```
if(isTRUE(All_companies[i, 1] == All_companies[i + 1, 1]))
```